# GDI+ behaving strangely across function calls

Tags: c++, gdi+

I am calling for help as GDI+ is driving me nuts ...

Basically, the following function call works like a charm and draws a rectangle at the requested location :

```
mGraphics->Clear(Gdiplus::Color(255,255,0));
mGraphics->DrawRectangle(...)
```

But, if I move the `DrawRectangle` call to a method of another object, and then go with :

```
mGraphics->Clear(Gdiplus::Color(255,255,0));
theObject->render(mGraphics);
```

Then the `DrawRectangle` is called but doesn't draw anything on screen.

I checked the pointer and it is valid and `==` at both locations, and the `DrawRectangle` function returns 0 which means OK - so now I really don't understand this behaviour which drives me nuts because it makes no sense ...

Thanks for your help!!

C.

Comment: I know it's hard with Windows programs, but can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `render` so we can see how you are passing the graphics object?

Comment: Need to see more code, it could be as simple as failing to pass something by reference. Or it could be something more complicated to do with initializing GDI plus properly. But we just don't know from what you've supplied...

Comment: "It's a bug in the operating system!" never gets you very far.  Ignoring the return value of these functions and not *at least* assert that you get Status::Ok does forever produce "it does not work" questions however.

Comment: Thanks guys ! I have checked all this - reference etc ... it's clearly the same Gdiplus::Graphics object being called from both locations - but the second one doesn't draw anything, tho the function returns 0 ... As for the minimal test case, hard to have one since the GDI+ layer is initialized by a flight simulator and the Gdiplus::Graphics is simply created from a HDC created by the simulator ...